# Autorun Module in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module in Excel that I need to run automatically whenever any cell is changed in the worksheet.

As it stands now, it runs if I go into edit mode on the cell that has the function in it and then hit enter or if i hit `Ctrl+Alt+F9`. 
How can I accomplish this? Also I don't much about VB or Excel macros and modules nor did I write this code.

This is the code that is in my module...

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

If SUM = True Then
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
        End If
            Next rCell
        Else
            For Each rCell In rRange
                If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Comment: When you change a value of a cell is Conditional Formatting used to change the interior colour of the cell?

Comment: No the cells have to be manually colored because we are tracking port usage in our patch panels.

Comment: Changing a colour does not trigger an event, or a re-calculation. You'll have to do as you are currently, or press a button, to run the code. You could, I suppose, use `Application.OnTime` to run a regular procedure to check if the cell-colour has changed. This is not a great solution as (in my opinion) it tends to slow Excel and is easy for it to be interrupted. Another option is to create a process that allows the user to change the colour, which can then also re-calculate the formula.

Comment: Conditional Formatting - changing a value, which also happens to change the colour - is a better option.

Comment: There isn't any information in the cells apart from the the color though.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply put `Application.Volatile` in the beginning of your macro, this seems to work as expected when I test it, however note Andy G's commenet above:

> ...changing a colour won't cause a recalc, nor trigger the Change event ...Changing the cell value has no effect on the formula result

If you do want the color change to trigger the re-calculation, we would need a different approach.

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
Application.Volatile
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

If SUM = True Then
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
        End If
            Next rCell
        Else
            For Each rCell In rRange
                If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Comment: Ok so it seems that coloring a cell doesn't count as "changing" a cell but this recalculates whenever I edit a cell. Hmmmmmm I wonder if there is a way to cause it to trigger when you color a cell.

Comment: Right, simply coloring a cell doesn't trigger any event nor force a calculation under any circumstances.  **HOWEVER** I think it would re-calculate *if* the cells' colors are given by conditional formatting rule(s) -- because these are evaluated formulae.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make them color based on conditional formatting because I am tracking port usage in our patch panels and we never know when cables will be added or removed.

Comment: I don't know why you think that precludes you from using conditional formatting. Of course you will have to *maintain* the formatting rules  and periodically update them, but you certain **CAN** use conditional formatting...

Comment: I don't understand how I would do that then.

Comment: [Do you want me to do your job for you?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm not a developer if that is what you think. My job is to rack servers, run cables, and make patch plans. I failed out of multiple programming classes because I don't get it. :(

Comment: Regardless of your job title, the point remains: If you haven't tried anything, and you're simply looking for a ready-made solution, you're not going to find it here. Now, we've explained very clearly why the current approach is not working (and you seem to grok that just fine), and have suggested that you try to use conditional formatting. If you don't know how to use that,[now would be a good time to try and learn](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html).

Comment: I know how to use conditional formatting but not how to use it in this case. I don't understand how I would make the cell color the color I need it to based on what ports are empty out in the panels. There isn't data in the cells for the conditional formatting to trigger off of. It's just P1 through P48 over and over again.

Comment: Gonna need to have some idea of what your worksheet looks like...  I would suggest asking a new question.  Include some examples of this worksheet and how you active use it (i.e., manually changing cell colors based on physical panel/port inspection, etc.).  You should probably also close this question by accepting the answer (sometimes the answer is "This can't be done the way you are asking for it to be done").

Comment: No it's not really worth the effort. I'm just going to put a big note on every sheet in the workbook that says Remember: If you change the cell color hit Ctrl+Alt+F9 so that the formulas recalculate.

Comment: the only other option that kind of does what you want is to put `Me.Calculate` in the worksheet's `Selection_Change` event.  THis will force calculation any time you *select* a cell. Of course though you select a cell *prior* to changing it's color, so you would have to tab out of that cell, and then the formula should update.  Or, [Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/574405-capturing-cell-color-change-visual-basic-applications.html) is an interesting solution, although it would take some tweaking to meet your needs, the functionality looks correct.